# timestamp shown in the rails dbconsole but not in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can see the timestamp value in the db:

```
select id, measured_on from measurements where measured_on is not null;
  id  |        measured_on         
------+----------------------------
 1717 | 2015-02-08 23:55:11.689849
```

But not in rails, I am getting nil:

```
2.1.5 :001 > @measurement = Measurement.find_by(id: 1717)
2.1.5 :007 > @measurement.measured_on
 => nil
```

Also the fields created_at and updated_at are visible in the db but not in rails.
What is wrong here?

Comment: In the rails console after this: `@measurement = Measurement.find_by(id: 1717)` just type `@measurement` and see if you getting the record or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented this line in the config/application.rb file:

## config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

Problem solved. Server needs to be restarted after this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. But to check again just in the console after this:

```
@measurement = Measurement.find_by(id: 1717)
```

type `@measurement` and see what you get. You should get a hash which should show all the records of your `Measurement` table like `created_at, updated_at, measured_on` etc. If you don't get this then actually you have some problem in the above `find`. For finding just by `id` what you can do is:

```
@measurement = Measurement.find(1717)
```

This will by default find by id. Hope this helps.

Comment: 2.1.5 :004 > @measurement = Measurement.find_by(id: 1717)
  Measurement Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "measurements".* FROM "measurements"  WHERE "measurements"."id" = 1717 LIMIT 1
 => #<Measurement id: 1717, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, instrument_id: 3028, scheduled_on: "2015-02-08", reading_type: "Baseline", reading_frequency: "Once", reading_period: "Daily", baseline_value: nil, measured_value: nil, measured_by: nil, measured_on: nil, measured_with: nil, crew: nil, weather: nil, temperature: nil, scheduled_by: "Levi L. Damian">

Comment: 2.1.5 :005 > @measurement
 => #<Measurement id: 1717, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, instrument_id: 3028, scheduled_on: "2015-02-08", reading_type: "Baseline", reading_frequency: "Once", reading_period: "Daily", baseline_value: nil, measured_value: nil, measured_by: nil, measured_on: nil, measured_with: nil, crew: nil, weather: nil, temperature: nil, scheduled_by: "Levi L. Damian"> 
2.1.5 :006 >

Comment: instrumon_dev=# select id, measured_on from measurements where measured_on is not null;
  id  |        measured_on         
------+----------------------------
 1717 | 2015-02-08 23:55:11.689849

Comment: ```2.1.5 :001 > @measurement = Measurement.find(1717)
  Measurement Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "measurements".* FROM "measurements"  WHERE "measurements"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1717]]
 => #<Measurement id: 1717, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, instrument_id: 3028, scheduled_on: "2015-02-08", reading_type: "Baseline", reading_frequency: "Once", reading_period: "Daily", baseline_value: nil, measured_value: nil, measured_by: nil, measured_on: nil, measured_with: nil, crew: nil, weather: nil, temperature: nil, scheduled_by: "Levi L. Damian">```

Comment: ```2.1.5 :002 > @measurement
 => #<Measurement id: 1717, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, instrument_id: 3028, scheduled_on: "2015-02-08", reading_type: "Baseline", reading_frequency: "Once", reading_period: "Daily", baseline_value: nil, measured_value: nil, measured_by: nil, measured_on: nil, measured_with: nil, crew: nil, weather: nil, temperature: nil, scheduled_by: "Levi L. Damian"> 
2.1.5 :003 >```

Comment: ```instrumon_dev=# select id, measured_on from measurements where measured_on is not null;
  id  |        measured_on         
------+----------------------------
 1717 | 2015-02-08 23:55:11.689849
(1 row)
```

Comment: Same result, the measured_on is visible in the db but not in rails.

Comment: Are you sure you are on the same database? And have you tried restarting the terminal?

Comment: I have only one database, Postgress, up and running. That table and column exists only in that database. The same happens to the collumns created_at and updated_at which are generated by the ActiveModel in the same time with the id. I restarted several times all: terminal, computer, server, etc.